# ODP.NET Pass large byte array to PL/SQL stored procedure accepting blob

Tags: .net, oracle, plsql, blob, odp.net

I have a PL/SQL stored procedure accepting a BLOB argument (among other arguments) and executes an insert of the BLOB into a table. How can I pass a large (1MB and greater) byte array from .NET to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

As of Oracle 11.2/ODP.Net v2.112.1.2, you can't pass an array of `BLOB`s. From [Oracle® Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.3), PL/SQL Associative Array Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/featOraCommand.htm#autoId8):

> ...ODP.NET supports binding parameters of PL/SQL Associative Arrays
>   which contain the following data types.
>
> ```
>   BINARY_FLOAT
>   CHAR
>   DATE
>   NCHAR
>   NUMBER
>   NVARCHAR2
>   RAW
>   ROWID
>   UROWID
>   VARCHAR2
> ```
>
> Using unsupported data types with associative arrays can cause an ORA-600 error.

Note too: [Oracle Forums: Passing Associative Array of BLOBs Not Supported](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2275033).

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting up your SP query (getting ready to Prepare it) set the the data type of the parameter to `OracleDbType.Blob`.

```
OracleParameter p = query.CreateParameter();
p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Blob;
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

Then right before you run the query simply set the parameter's value to the big BLOB you're mentioning.